# Editing Android Layout using Eclipse ADT

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, ide, adt

Sorry for a noobish question,

So I have eclipse, installed ADT, the sdk etc and everything is fine....I can click on an android layout xml and the ADT layout editor displays fine...so I closed eclipse

A couple weeks later, I open eclipse again, but then when I open an android layout xml, the layout editor does not display and it instead displays xml...how can I get android ADT's layout editor to display? Is there a specific perspective/configuration that I must access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two case:

1) You open that file by `Text Editor`. That default of Eclipse (and you have it before you install ADT). This is fast but not trivial to add/edit something in Android. With this case, nothing can done. (mean you can not use ADT layout editor to fix it) Just close the tab and do other thing (That I will say later)

2) You have changed to `Text Mode`. With your question, I think you don't know that `Android layout editor` has two mode: one for graphic and one for text (same with above). For this case, you should close this tab to have same case with above :D

Fix:

Choose your layout xml file. Right click choose `open with` and choose `Android layout editor`.

You will see :
[image: Example]

As you see in picture above (I color two tab), you just click to each tab and see magically. ( I think :P). (In your case, click to `Graphical Layout`)

Notes: this trick will same with many others in `Android` (`Android Manifest file`... ) as you will see when choose `open with`.

Hope that will help you. Before that, I have met error like you. ;)

Comment: The thing is, when I go to the "design" tab, it instead displays a table of xml nodes with node & contents column instead of the widgets, etc

Comment: @kamikaze_pilot Can you give me your screenshot,please :)

Answer (score 0):

There should be a tab on the bottom of the xml window, where you can switch between layout and xml.

Comment: The thing is, when I go to the "design" tab, it instead displays a table of xml nodes with node & contents column instead of the widgets, etc

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you've opened the .xml file in the Android Layout Editor. To be certain, right-click on the file and choose Open With from the pop-up menu.
2. If it's already open in the Layout Editor, look at the bottom; there are two tabs, one for Design ("visual" mode) and another for Source. You might be looking at the Source tab.

Comment: The thing is, when I go to the "design" tab, it instead displays a table of xml nodes with node & contents column instead of the widgets, etc

Comment: Then you haven't opened the file in the Android Layout Editor. See my step 1. above.